# need some sesionFactory clarification

Tags: hibernate

So I read the doc and it cites that "The SessionFactory is heavyweight obj so usually it is created during application start up and kept for later use. You would need one SessionFactory object per database using a separate configuration file.".

1. When the application start up? Will it be at the moment user accept to the website? Or it is the moment the user perform a transaction?
2. How can we keep the sessionFactory for later use?
3. What does it mean by "using a separate configuration file"?

Thank you for your clarification.

Bonus: I recently heard the work "expensive" or "costly". How does connecting to the database or performing a transaction are "expensive"?

Comment: 1 neither - at application start up means just that. 2 - store it in the `ServletContext` or a Singleton Pattern. I assume this is a web app. 3 - if using `hibernate.cfg.xml` to configure, you need a different file for each db you wish to connect to.

Comment: Thank you. It is a web app. I am still unclear on application startup :(

Comment: You probably need to read more about how web apps work in Java. You need a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which will be notified of application startup.

Comment: Definitely. There are a lot of mysterious terminologies that I don't know or understand, especially when it comes to xxxContext. Thank for the link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Application start up for web application commonly means the **process of deployment**, because during this process, all beans are initialized and so on. The session factory would be a bean, so this is what the docs are talking about.
2. For web applications, you could simply use beans. Define the bean in a XML configuration file and inject it where you need it. Beans are more or less singletons which are automatically created **on application startup**.
3. There might be applications using more than just one database backend. When you use more than one database, you need to specify more than one session factory bean. Of course, you would also need different data source definitions, but you only use **one** Hibernate configuration file.

Bonus: I think you heard "costly" and "expensive" relating to the creation of the session factory, not the transactions. Of course, there might be transactions that take their time but they are not necessarily costly. Connecting to a database should be pretty clear. When you connect to a database, there's a TCP socket created in the background, the protocol has to be initialized, you have to be logged in and so on.

I hope I managed to answer your questions with this post. If something's not clear yet, feel free to comment and I try to answer it better.